# Serilog: writing to custom fields without dirtying up the "message" field (mssql server)

Tags: serilog

I have added bunch of columns to the sql server logging which works great.  But one thing is that it makes my "message" field dirty with all the custom field info, for example
`Board` and `Process` both are custom fields in my log table

I have the following

`_logger.LogInformation("Record count {RecordCount}, Board = {Board}, Process = {Process}", 20, boardName, processName);`

I would like the message part to say `"Record count 20"` and not have the rest included in the message as they are going to their own fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ForContext` extensions on `ILogger` do that:-

```
Log.ForContext("Board",boardName)
   .ForContext("Process",processName)
   .Information("Record count {RecordCount}", 20)
```

Such properties can alternately be fed in using the [`Enrich.FromLogContext` / `LogContext.PushProperty` mechanisms](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment#the-logcontext)